# Pass a List<> of object as parameter to SQL stored proc

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

I would like to pass a List<> of object say `List<Student>` to the parameter of stored proc and have the data stored in corresponding fields in the database. How can I do this? I use SQL Server 2005.

So if the database Table has fields StudentId,Name,Age and the object `List<Student>` has the same properties containing the data, then the data should go to the corresponding fields in Table.

Please advice with code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do that. You'd have to make a function of your own that accepts such a list and calls the stored procedure once for each item in it.

Comment: You would be better of iterating the List<Student> and inserting one at a time.

Comment: You will need a function to make a string (member1, member2...) from you list. 
than you can pass this string as parameter to SP. SQL Query should be like 'select * from table where students in ( @ parameter )'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can pass List by convert it in to XML and pass as parameter
[Passing lists to SQL Server 2005 with XML Parameters](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters)